# ListView with few lists in one Activity

Tags: java, android

I try to put something like menu picker in ListView with only one Activity.
Only one XML file, one Activity one ListAdapter but few lists with items to fill it.

I am trying to do it like this:
on **OnItemClickListener**, i get item position, save it and open another list , according to our choose.
it's work, but only on first click. When i try choose 1st option 2 times then OnClick method jump from first list to last. When i try pick 1st option and then any other it's work's perfect

But it will be nice to have all options available for all the options on the list :)

any other way to make something like this? or to fix this? of course i can create xml file and activity for every single list, but when you have like 20 different combinations it's not good option :D

Comment: Thought about using ListFragment??